# Why was Will Salas so sure that Timekeepers would not jump through the window?

Tags: plot-explanation, in-time

In the movie [*In Time* (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1637688/), only Timekeeper Raymond Leon shows the will to chase them, but the rest of the Timekeepers don't show as much desire to chase and catch them.

Answer (score 3):

Because most of the Time Keepers came from the upper class/more wealthy parts.  As such, they aren't used to having to take risks and shortcuts like those of lower class.  This is a part of what separates Raymond from his fellow Time Keepers; he knows the streets and is used to taking risks and short cuts to get what he wants because he grew up poor.

In the established universe, those of higher class have the luxury of taking their time to do things.  They don't have to run everywhere just to stay alive.  As such, unless it's for something fun they have no real reason to do dangerous things, such as jumping out of windows.

Comment: oh...yes...so do you think that most of them are from upper class? but why main antagonist claim they are paid low?

Comment: @SSimon they aren't paid low, but they (or at least Raymond) keeps his time low so that would be time thiefs and Time Keeper killers can't make off with a lot of time.  For example, a real world cop wouldn't carry their full month's wage around on them on patrol and display that they're carrying it around.

Comment: I feel this is the correct answer. Even if the time keepers did not get paid much, they had the guarantee of making enough to live forever from their per-Diem. Just like the others who had enough time, they were not accustomed to taking any risks that would comprise that prospect of eternal life. This is emphasized by when Will buys the Cobra, and is not expected to actually drive it.

Comment: Then this leaves the questions; why take the job of Time Keeper if you're not going to do what it takes to enforce the laws, and how do you remain a Time Keeper if you don't do your job?

Comment: @JohnnyBones that can be asked of a lot of occupations in the real world...

Comment: @JohnnyBones you need to start look at the time as upper class do, it is iternal.

Comment: If you are a Time Keeper (which is essentially a police officer of sorts) and every one of your criminals gets away because you let them, I don't think it matters *what* class you come from; you're not going to have that job long.

Answer (score 1):

Will wasn't so sure Raymond wouldn't jump, but he took a risk to stick around and watch knowing that if Raymond attempted it, he'd still have time to get away.  It was a calculated risk, because Will wanted to know how close the Timekeepers were to him.  If he just ran, he'd never know if they jumped or not, and he'd have no idea which escape route was more likely to work.